# Any alternative firewall solutions for debian that aren't based on netfilter / iptables?

Tags: debian, iptables, vps, linux-vserver

I have a virtual server running Debian. It's host OS is using Linux Vserver and due to its lack of support for network namespaces, using iptables to secure the box is not an option.  I did many searches looking for alternatives but so far I'm only finding different front ends to manage iptables itself.

Is there anything else out there? I was hoping to tie it in into my OSSEC active response scripts to enable real time blocking when malicious activity is detected.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, iptables is *the* linux firewall. Never in all my years working with linux have I ever heard nor seen of any alternatives.

Do you have the option of just running the firewall layer on the host OS?

Comment: iptables is not a firewall. It's a user-space tool to manipulate the firewall, netfilter.

Comment: @petrus - True, but probably not worth the pedantry.

Comment: @petrus - also, feel free to edit my answer (or any others) to correct/clarify.

Comment: And thank god for it -- beat the heck out of ipchains.

Comment: No unfortunately I do not have access to the host OS, and since this is on a shared server I doubt they would be willing to yield to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

There's always Debian [GNU/kFreeBSD](http://www.debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-gnu/) which ports the FreeBSD kernel the Debian/GNU userland. This would allow you to use pf as your firewall. Unfortunately, as of current (Debian 6/Squeeze) GNU/kFreeBSD is considered a "techninical preview", which means not ready for production.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux kernel has only one built-in firewall, iptables.

There are side projects like dummynet, a Linux port of the BSD firewall, but these are for testing purposes and not to be used in production.

Dummynet: http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/

Comment: dummynet is not firewall, it is a simple traffic shaper.

Answer (score 0):

ip filter claims to support Linux. (I have only used it on Solaris.) http://coombs.anu.edu.au/~avalon/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the `nftables`. It is gaining momentum and AFAIK it is going to replace `iptables`.

Comment: The "nf" in "nftables" stands for "netfilter".  Thus it is fairly likely based on netfilter.

Answer (score -3):

What about Bastille Linux? It can be used as firewall.

http://www.bastille-linux.org/

Comment: What makes you think that that is not netfilter-based?